# Using (Java) Eclipse abilities in other programming language

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, linden-scripting-language

I use Eclipse mainly for LSL (linden Scripting language). The plug-in for this language does not provide things like templates or task-tag recognition. Is there any way that these kind of features in LSL-files (or any other generic file/code for that matter) can be used?

Comment: Technically speaking, there's *always* a way. It just depends on how much work you want to do. Of course, I presume what you meant to ask is if there's already a pre-built solution...

Comment: Ah, yes. I am no expert on developing my own plug-ins unfortunately. Java has always eluded me for some reason. Plus, I am getting too old to be able to rummage in someone else's code without getting confused, my attention-span is not what it used to be ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Take look at the [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) project. If you can define the grammar of LSL there it will generate full Eclipse plugin for it,  complete with syntax Highlighting, code Completion, validation and quick Fixes and more.

Answer (score 1):

Another one to try (one i use myself) is [LSL Editor](http://www.lsleditor.org/)

Full Syntax highlighting, code suggest, and even a off world run time environment. plus able to test multiple scripts by building test objects with prims.

Take a Look :)

Answer (score 0):

[LSLForge](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LSLForge) is being actively maintained, and has most of what you describe. If there's something missing, the developer is always looking for new challenges.